# Excel Remove Blanks with Substitute Function

Tags: excel

I have an Excel table that my coworkers will use to create new user accounts. In one of the columns I have this formula that creates email addresses based on user input in the first, middle, and last name columns.

```
=LOWER(([First Name]&"."&IF([Middle Name]<>"",LEFT([Middle Name],1)&".",""))&[Last Name])&"@test.com"
```

(Middle name is optional hence the if statement)

My question is how do I add the SUBSTITUTE function to this formula so that blanks in names will be ignored?

An example would be for a new user that has the last name of "Santos de Dios".

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify. I want to remove blanks from all three of the name columns (first, middle, and last). In my example I used last name because that field has the highest likelihood of containing spaces.

Comment: `=SUBSTITUTE(...," ","")` Where `...` is your formula.

Comment: Thanks! Can you post that as an answer so I can mark it as such? I knew that there was an easy answer...my brain is just fried today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your formula in `SUBSTITUTE(...," ","")`

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(([First Name]&"."&IF([Middle Name]<>"",LEFT([Middle Name],1)&".",""))&[Last Name])&"@test.com"," ","")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
=LOWER((SUBSTITUTE("First Name"," ","") &"."&IF("Middle Name"<>"",LEFT(TRIM("Middle Name"),1)&".",""))&SUBSTITUTE("Santos de Dios"," ","")&"@test.com")
```

You might want to use Trim on first and last names as well to ensure no extra unwanted white space at the start/end of strings.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I ended up going with the solution posted by Scott Craner.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(CONCAT([First Name],".",[Middle Name],if([Middle Name]="", "", "."), [Last Name],"@test.com"))," ","")
```

Input of Michael (First) Jon (Middle) Santos Dios (Last). Just use `CONCAT` to string it all together, `LOWER` to move to lowercase, and then `SUBSTITUTE` to clear the spaces.

Returns `michael.jon.santosdios@test.com`

Comment: OP wants `.` between the names, hence the use of the IF() to not have `..` when no middle is provided.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Mako212. Scott is correct though. His solution provided works.